# SP2010, How to get value from DatePicker in InfoPath (Form Library) template

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have one date picker in my form. its simple form and no rules and data sources added in this form. this template is used for Form Library (not custom list)

I am having VSTA project as my backend for code my question is :

1. how i can get selected date value of date picker in my code (VSTA  code).
2. how i can put break point in VSTA code.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code:

```
 XPathNavigator myNav = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();                
                XPathNavigator workflowDataNav = this.DataSources[0].CreateNavigator();                
                XPathNavigator newNode = myNav.SelectSingleNode("//my:field7", this.NamespaceManager);

                if (newNode.MoveToAttribute("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"))
                    newNode.DeleteSelf();
                newNode.SetValue(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Have you looked ad the following:
[How to: Debug Browser-Enabled Forms Deployed on InfoPath Form Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa944831%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

[How to: Preview and Debug InfoPath Managed Code Form Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa947485%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Madhur .. thnx for your valuable help... I am writing this code in _Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e) event .... ..... actually i am not able to attach break point in my VSTA code and may i have SPWeb in this code of contexts  ?? . .. any idea ? ...

Comment: Hi MAdhur.. i got it .. I have to upload this in Central Administration -> General settings->Manage Form Templates and will attched to a form library but i am still struggling to get SPWeb FormWeb = SPContext.Current.Web; , it shows me "System.Security.SecurityException".

Comment: Hi Madhur ..again i need help ... all above things are sorted out .. now i have taken one boolean field=boolApprovalNeeded and created one rule (in designer) when that field is true that rule will fire and will show message....i have written assigning value to boolApprovalNeeded in _Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e) but when i assign it .. this rule is not validating (firing).. pls help me ...

Comment: hi ... actually when i open my web form in browser my date picker events are not fired and not coming under break points...any reasons ??....